# Can an object with constant centralized velocity move in an orbit?

Tags: orbital-motion, rotational-kinematics

Suppose I have a device where there is a rotating friction-less horizontal table in the shape of a wheel that can be moved to any desired angular speed centered around a static axle.  On this axle is a pulley.  If the centralized pulley pulls an object with constant velocity across the rotating horizontal table, is there a specific speed that the table can be rotated so that the object being pulled across the rotating table moves in a closed circular orbit?

My thought is if the table is rotated in such a way that the speed of its rotation is decelerating, then perhaps the object being dragged to the center at constant velocity could indeed move in a circular orbit, at least temporarily.  This is a more practical version of a strangely-worded question I asked yesterday.  Does anyone have any thoughts?  Is my hypothesis correct?  The math to prove or disprove the hypothesis is difficult for me.

Comment: First, this is more of a math question than physics. The math site might be a better place to ask. Second, it is hard to visualize your device. Can you draw a picture? Also, google cycloid and curate cycloid. They aren't exactly what you are asking about, but they might help.

Comment: Is the pulley mounted so that its axis is vertical or horizontal? I'm having difficulty in picturing your setup. Plus, there are at least three convenient reference frames for describing the  object velocity the problem: 1) at rest with the pulley, 2) at rest with the table.  3) at rest with the room containing the table.  Maybe 1) and 2) are the same, depending on how the pulley is mounted. Please clarify by editing your question.

Comment: Good points.  I'd say the reference point would be at rest with both the pulley and at rest with the room containing the table.

Comment: And I forgot to mention that the object being pulled by the pulley can also pull back.  The rope isn't quite so tense to not allow pullback.  But you guys are right I think this question is too complicated without drawing a picture.